# background image css not working in rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Am using the background-image property in my rails app, i have used it previously, it's pretty easy and it works all the time but don't know why it's not working now.

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../assets/mainbanner.jpg");
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: no of-course it is not displayed, that why i said it is not working, it flicker a little at the time of page loading @VXp

Comment: If you find any answer suitable you can mark it correct

Answer (score 2):

The Rails way is by using the [Rails assets helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) to get the correct path to assets. This also adds a cache-busting fragment to the url which avoids issues with stale cached assets.

It also lets you for example later switch to Content delivery network (CDN) for assets without having to to deal with hardcoded paths in your CSS/JS and views.

You can do this in two ways:

### 1. ERB (Embedded Ruby)

Change the extension of the file to `.css.erb`

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("<%= asset_path('mainbanner.jpg') %>");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
```

Using the extension `.erb` causes the file to be sent through the ERB interpreter. This is very much the same as using ERB to create HTML in your views.

### 2. SASS-Rails

Make sure you have the [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem installed and change the file extension name to `.scss`.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(asset_path('mainbanner.jpg'));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
```

SASS rails maps the Rails assets helpers to SASS functions. The SASS compiler then inserts the correct url when the stylesheet is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

```css
background-image: url('~images/shared/sign-page1.jpg');
```

worked for me with public images

Comment: Please elaborate on why your code works. Just posting code sample doesn't work. People coming to read your answer must understand how and why this code works and not just blindly copy and paste it.

Answer (score -2):

Change your .css file to .scss and try this

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(asset_path('mainbanner.jpg'));
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
background-image: url('/assets/mainbanner.jpg');
```